# Run bitcoin-qt at startup of Windows server

Tags: bitcoin-core, server, windows, bitcoin-qt-setup

I am running `bitcoin-qt` on my server. I use `.Net` library to query it through windows services. 
It all works when I start `bitcoin-qt` manually.
But if the server is restarted, I see that it is running in task manager (bitcoin-qt.exe), but it is not available for services.
I also tried to run it as administrator using the scheduler, but this did not help.

Comment: If you're in a server environment you probable want bitcoind, the headless version of Bitcoin Core rather than QT, the GUI.

Comment: You might need to pass `-server` as startup argument when using Bitcoin-Qt (bitcoind will autolaunch the RPC server, Qt not).

Comment: What method do you use to launch it manually?

Answer (score 0):

when you run bitcoin-d I believe it's with configuration allowing remote calls to query the wallet . as soon as windows restart you will need to have this exe run with the params ,can achieve this with batch file. 
and remove the on startup run of the default bitcoin-qt.exe